# Dynamic ordering/sorting in a linq-to-sql query

Tags: linq-to-sql

Say I am selecting rows from my article table, but I want to dynamically sort by specific columns and sort by des/asc.

Say my method signature looks like:

```
public List<Article> GetArticles(SortBy sort, SortOrder order)
{

}
```

Is there a way to do this with linq-to-sql?

Answer (score 0):

I recently used [Dynamite](http://www.codeplex.com/dynamite) to do this. It worked great for me.